# ¿Como insertar las letras de un String en 3 diferentes pilas? [JAVA]

Tags: java, pilas, stack

Alguien que me pueda dar una idea de como resolver este problema. Lo que tengo que hacer es:

Tengo 3 pilas de char. El usuario ingresa una palabra ejemplo: **"hola"**. Despues tengo que agregar cada una de las letras en las pilas, 1 letra por pila, por ejemplo quedaria asi:

1. PILA 1: ['h', 'a']
2. PILA 2: ['o']
3. PILA 3: ['l']

EL OUTPUT QUE ME DA CON ESTE CODIGO ES:

1. PILA 1: ['h',]
2. PILA 2: ['o']
3. PILA 3: ['l']

Eso es porque en la variable de aumento, le digo a "i", que va a tomar el valor de la suma de el numero de elementos de todas las pilas, y queda en 3, eso hace que se rompa la condicion del "for" y solo entre 1 vez.

Este codigo que hice, solo me funciona cuando la palabra que ingresa el usuario tiene espacios, y aun no se de que manera podria resolverlo.

Codigo de MAIN

```
public class MensajeSecreto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String palabra;
        System.out.println("Ingresa tu palabra");
        palabra = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Tu palabra es: " + palabra);
        PilaChar pilaChar1 = new PilaChar(palabra.length());
        PilaChar pilaChar2 = new PilaChar(palabra.length());
        PilaChar pilaChar3 = new PilaChar(palabra.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length() - 2; i = pilaChar1.numElementos() + pilaChar2.numElementos()
                + pilaChar3.numElementos()) {
            pilaChar1.insertar(palabra.charAt(i));
            pilaChar2.insertar(palabra.charAt(i + 1));
            pilaChar3.insertar(palabra.charAt(i + 2));
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pilaChar1.getP()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pilaChar2.getP()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pilaChar3.getP()));

    }
```

Codigo de PilaChar

```
public class PilaChar {
    private char[] p; // vector para guardar datos, únicamente se declara
    private int tope; // apuntador al último elemento de la pila

    // public PilaChar() {
    // p = new char[5];
    // tope = -1;
    // }

    public PilaChar(int n) {
        p = new char[n];
        tope = -1;
    }

    public char[] getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public int getTope() {
        return tope;
    }

    public void setP(char[] p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public void setTope(int tope) {
        this.tope = tope;
    }

    public void insertar(char nuevo) {
        if (!estaLlena()) {
            tope++;
            p[tope] = nuevo;
        }
    }

    public char eliminar() {
        char borrado = ' '; // variable que devuelve el dato borrado
        if (!estaVacia()) {
            borrado = p[tope]; // se saca el dato del tope
            p[tope] = ' '; // se borra físicamente la casilla
            tope--; // se decrementa el tope
        }
        return borrado; // se devuelve el valor eliminado
    }

    public boolean estaVacia() {
        if (tope == -1) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean estaLlena() {
        if (tope == p.length - 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public char datoEnTope() {
        if (!estaVacia())
            return p[tope];
        return ' ';
    }

    public int numElementos() {
        return tope + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = "Elementos en la pila:\n";
        for (int i = tope; i >= 0; i--) {
            s += p[i] + "\n";
        }
        s += "Fin de de la pila";

        return s;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres puedes usar el resto de la operación entera de la posición de cada letra y el número de pilas donde las quieres ir repartiendo.

Si tienes una palabra por ejemplo de 10 letras, y las quieres ir repartiendo en 3 pilas, vas extrayendo cada letra y según su posición en la palabra de las 10 letras, el resto de la división entre 3 te dice dónde la tienes que guardar. El resto de la división entera entre 3 de cualquier número te tiene que dar 0, 1, ó 2 (de un número n tendría que ser de 0 a n-1).

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int resto = i % 3;
    if( resto == 0)
        System.out.println( "A la pila 1");
    else if( resto == 1)
        System.out.println( "A la pila 2");
    else
        System.out.println( "A la pila 3");
}
```

En tu caso, la longitud no sería 10, sino la longitud de la palabra introducida.